# What is good image processing algorithm for comparing differences in video frames?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am looking for a good (simple, relatively fast) algorithm for comparing video frames and calculating the difference between the frames.  I imagine a function like this:

`//Same Scene

diff = ImageDiff(FrameInScene1, nextFrameInScene1);
//diff is low

//Scene Boundary

diff = ImageDiff(FrameInScene2, nextFrameInScene3);
//diff is high`

Where diff is a numeric value of the similarity/difference between the frames.  For example, two adjacent frames in the same scene would have low values, but a scene change would have very high values.

**Note:** I am not looking for a scene detection algorithm (some are timecode based), but this would be a good example of the problem.

A library with C# code would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

Consecutive frames ? Mean Squared Error, Mean Absolute Error, PSNR.

Given so little information about your problem it doesn't make sense to suggest anything more.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of C#! Have you used openCV? I wrote the code in C and I had used the BHATTACHARYA algorithm for comparing. You can use OpenCV from c# also look at : http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page.

All you would be doing is:

1. Grab the two frames.
2. Get the histograms of these in two separate pointer.
3. Pass these two pointers and use a normalization factor and compare the histograms.

I hope this helps.